# JavaScript - Why is the else alert executing with the if ones

Tags: javascript, if-statement, alert

It happens in PHP as well. Whenever pass1 is entered to the prompt popup, the alert below it shows up as usual. But after that, the alert box of else also shows up. How can I stop the alert box of else from executing on pass1?

```
function download()
{
x=prompt("Enter the download code here.")
if (x=="pass1")
{
alert("This function has been deleted by the administrator. Jeff, get the hell out       of here.")
}
if (x=="pass2")
{
alert("I like pie too.")
}
else
{
alert("The code you specified was invalid.")
}
}
```

Comment: You really should indent your code. It's very hard to read right now.

Comment: That is why else if is implemented

Answer (score 5):

Change

```
if (x=="pass2")
```

to

```
else if (x=="pass2")
```

[if/elseif/else documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php)

Comment: Thanks. I can't believe it's that simple. I once came across it, but I didn't know what it was for.

Answer (score 2):

Try with `else if` like

```
if (x=="pass1")
{
    alert("This function has been deleted by the administrator. Jeff, get the hell out       of here.")
}
else if (x=="pass2")    // Here use else if
{
    alert("I like pie too.")
}
else
{
    alert("The code you specified was invalid.")
}
```

You can also use `switch` like

```
switch(x) {
    case "pass1" : 
                  alert('This function has been deleted by the administrator. Jeff, get the hell out       of here.');
                  break;
    case "pass2" :
                  alert('I like pie too.');
                  break;
    default : 
             alert('The code you specified was invalid.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an `else if`

```
function download()
{
x=prompt("Enter the download code here.")
if (x=="pass1")
{
alert("This function has been deleted by the administrator. Jeff, get the hell out       of here.")
}
else if (x=="pass2")
{
alert("I like pie too.")
}
else
{
alert("The code you specified was invalid.")
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things,

`if` blocks execute if passed. When they fail, they try to find any associated `else` block and execute. The `if` context is lost after this point.

Your code basically says:

If x=='pass1' -> show Get the hell out of here.
Else block is not present.

If x=='pass2' -> Tell him you like pie too. ( :/ )
Else -> Show msg that code is invalid.

So, basically when someone runs the code with pass1, they are told to get lost. THEN, another check is performed for pass2 and since this fails, they are shown the invalid code error.

Solution, use `else if` statements as pointed in other solutions or even Better [use switch case.](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Because in your condition `if (x=="pass1")` satisfied so it prompts "pass1",

Then as you have used one another if statement which is `if (x=="pass2")` also get satisfied as this is different than your above if condition.

So its better to use `if` and `else if` for your condition.

Your code should be like this,

```
if (x=="pass1")
{
    alert("This function has been deleted by the administrator. Jeff, get the hell out       of here.")
}
else if (x=="pass2")    // use of else if
{
    alert("I like pie too.")
}
else
{
    alert("The code you specified was invalid.")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have used two `if` statements but for your solution it needs to be single `if` statement.

So just replacing your second `if` statement with `else if`.

e.g,

```
if (x=="pass1")
{
    alert("This function has been deleted by the administrator. Jeff, get the hell out       of here.")
}
else if (x=="pass2")    // else if
{
    alert("I like pie too.")
}
else
{
    alert("The code you specified was invalid.")
}
```